# Using ObservaleList to add element into ListView

Tags: java, swing, javafx

I am having the problem with adding an array to ObservableList the use it to add that array into ListView. When I compiled, I got NullPointerException. This exception occurs when I call the listAllItems() method. If I do not use the GUI control, instead of using switch-statement and letting the user choose the option, then there are no exception occur at the run time. Could someone help me figure out what happen? Thanks

Requirement

Create a LibraryGUI class
◦ This class should have a Library object as one of its fields. In the LibraryGUI constructor
you will need to call the library constructor method to initialize this field and then call its
open() method to read in the items from the data file.
◦ Use a JList to display the contents of the library. Use the setListData method of the JList
class together with the listAllItems method of the Library class to keep the list current with
the library contents.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class MediaItem {
/*Fields*/
private String title;
private String format;
private boolean onLoan;
private String loanedTo;
private String dateLoaned;

/*Default Constructor - Initialize string variables for null and boolean variable for false*/
public  MediaItem()
{
    title = null;
    format = null;
    onLoan = false;
    loanedTo = null;
    dateLoaned = null;
}

/*Parameterized Constructor*/
public MediaItem(String title, String format)
{
    this.title = title;
    this.format = format;
    this.onLoan = false;
}



public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getFormat() {
    return format;
}

public void setFormat(String format) {
    this.format = format;
}

public boolean isOnLoan() {
    return onLoan;
}

public void setOnLoan(boolean onLoan) {
    this.onLoan = onLoan;
}

public String getLoanedTo() {
    return loanedTo;
}

public void setLoanedTo(String loanedTo) {
    this.loanedTo = loanedTo;
}

public String getDateLoaned() {
    return dateLoaned;
}

public void setDateLoaned(String dateLoaned) {
    this.dateLoaned = dateLoaned;
}

/*Mark item on loan*/
  void markOnLoan(String name, String date){      
      if(onLoan == true)
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,this.title + " is already loaned out to " + this.loanedTo + " on " + this.dateLoaned);
      else {
              onLoan = true;
              loanedTo = name;
              dateLoaned = date;
      }
  }
/*Mark item return*/
      void markReturned(){
          if(onLoan == false)
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, this.title + " is not currently loaned out");
          onLoan = false; 
      }
```

}

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TextInputDialog;

public class Library extends MediaItem {
/*Fields*/
private ArrayList<MediaItem> itemsList = new ArrayList<>();




public ArrayList<MediaItem> getItemsList() {
    return itemsList;
}

public void setItemsList(ArrayList<MediaItem> itemsList) {
    this.itemsList = itemsList;
}
public int  displayMenu()
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("\nMenu Options \n"
                    +"\n1. Add new item\n"
                    +"\n2. Mark an item as on loan\n"
                    +"\n3. List all item\n"
                    +"\n4. Mark an item as returned\n"
                    +"\n5. Quit\n"
                    +"\n\nWhat would you like to do?\n");
    int choices =  input.nextInt();
    while (choices < 1 || choices >5)
    {
        System.out.println("I'm sorry, " + choices + " is invalid option");
        System.out.println("Please choose another option");
        choices = input.nextInt();
    }
    return (choices);
}

public void addNewItem(String title, String format)
{
    MediaItem  item = new MediaItem(); // the object of item
    /*Use the JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,prompt) to let the user input the title and the format
     * store the title and the format to the strings and pass it to the parameter of addNewItem(String, String) method 
     * title and format will go through the loop if title already exited let the user input another title and format
     * Using the same method JOptionPan.ShowInputDialog and JOptionPane.showMessage()
     */
    boolean matches = false;
    for(int i = 0; i< itemsList.size(); i++){
        if(title.equals(itemsList.get(i).getTitle())){
            String newTitle = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "this " + title + " already exited. Please enter the title again");

            String newFormat = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the format again");

             item = new MediaItem(newTitle,newFormat);
             itemsList.add(item);
             matches = true;

        }
    }if(!matches){
        item = new MediaItem(title,format);
        itemsList.add(item);
        }


}

public void markItemOnLoan(String title, String name, String date)
{
    boolean matches = false;
    for(int i = 0; i < itemsList.size(); i++)
    {   if (title.equals(itemsList.get(i).getTitle()))
        {
        itemsList.get(i).markOnLoan(name,date);
        matches = true;
        }
    } 
    if (!matches)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"I am sorry. I couldn't find " + title + " in the library");
    }

}

public String[] listAllItems()
{
    String[] list = new String[itemsList.size()];
    for (int n = 0; n < itemsList.size(); n++)
    {
        if(itemsList.get(n).isOnLoan() == true)
            list[n] = itemsList.get(n).getTitle() + " (" + itemsList.get(n).getFormat() + " ) loaned to " + itemsList.get(n).getLoanedTo() + " on " + itemsList.get(n).getDateLoaned();

            else
            list[n] = itemsList.get(n).getTitle() + " (" + itemsList.get(n).getFormat() + ")";
            if(list[n] == null){
                String title = "title ";
                String format = "format ";
                String loanTo = "name ";
                String date = "date ";
                list[n] = title + format + loanTo + date;
            }

    }
    return list;

}

public void markItemReturned(String title)
{
    boolean matches = false;
    for( int i = 0; i < itemsList.size(); i++)
    {
        if(title.equals(itemsList.get(i).getTitle()))
        {
            matches = true;
            itemsList.get(i).markReturned();
        }

    }
    if(!matches)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"I am sorry. I couldn't find " + title + " in the library");
    }
}
public void deleteItem(String title){
    boolean matches = false;
    for(int i = 0; i < itemsList.size(); i++){
        if(title.equals(itemsList.get(i).getTitle())){
            itemsList.get(i).setTitle(null);
            itemsList.get(i).setFormat(null);
            itemsList.get(i).setDateLoaned(null);
            itemsList.get(i).setLoanedTo(null);
            itemsList.get(i).setOnLoan(false);
        }
    }
    if(!matches)
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"I am sorry. I couldn't find " + title + " in the library");
}

public void openFile(){
    Scanner input = null; 
    try{
         input = new Scanner(new File("library.txt"));
         Scanner dataInput = null;
         MediaItem item = new MediaItem();
         int index = 0;
         String title = " ";
         String format = " ";
         String date = " ";
         String onLoanTo = " ";
         Boolean onLoan = false;
         Boolean checkString= false;
         Boolean checkBoolean = false;
         itemsList = new ArrayList<>();

         while(input.hasNextLine()){
             dataInput = new Scanner(input.nextLine());
             dataInput.useDelimiter("-");
             while(input.hasNext()){
                 Boolean dataBoolean = dataInput.nextBoolean();
                 String dataString = dataInput.next();

                 if(index == 0){
                     item.setTitle(dataString);
                     title = item.getTitle();
                     checkString = true; 
                 }else if(index == 1){
                     item.setFormat(dataString);
                     format = item.getFormat();
                     checkString= true;
                 }else if(index == 2){
                     item.setOnLoan(dataBoolean);
                     checkBoolean = true;
                 }else if(index == 3){
                     item.setLoanedTo(dataString);
                     checkString = true;
                 }else if(index == 4){
                     item.setDateLoaned(dataString);
                     checkString = true;
                 }else {
                    if(checkString == false)
                        throw new Exception("Invalid data " + dataString);
                    if(checkBoolean == false)
                        throw new Exception("Invalid data " + dataBoolean);
                 }
                 index++;
                 itemsList.add(new MediaItem(title,format));
             }
              index = 0;
              title = " ";
              format = " ";
              date = " ";
              onLoan = false;
              onLoanTo = " ";

              checkString= false;
              checkBoolean = false;
         }
     }catch(Exception ex){
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
     }finally{
         if(input != null){
             try{
                 input.close();
             }catch(NullPointerException ex){
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error: File can not be closed");
             }
         }
     }

}
public void saveFile(){

PrintWriter output = null;
    try{
     output = new PrintWriter(new File("library.txt"));
        for(int i = 0; i < itemsList.size(); i++){
             output.println(itemsList.get(i).getTitle() + "-" + itemsList.get(i).getFormat()+ "-" + itemsList.get(i).isOnLoan() + "-" 
                     + itemsList.get(i).getLoanedTo()   + "-" + itemsList.get(i).getDateLoaned());
        }
    }catch(FileNotFoundException e1){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Could not find the data file. Program is exiting.");
    }catch(IOException e2){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Something went wrong with writing to the data file.");
    }catch(Exception e3){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Something went wrong.");
    }
    finally{
        if( output != null){
            try{
            output.close();
            System.exit(0);
            }catch (NullPointerException e4){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: File can not be closed");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
enter code here

import java.util.ArrayList;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.SelectionMode;

public class LibraryGUI extends Application{
private ListView<String> listView;
private Library library;
private Button btAdd, btCheckIn, btCheckOut, btDelete;

public void LibraryGUI(){
    library = new Library();
    library.openFile();
}

public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    listView = new ListView<>();

    //Add all item in the listAllItem() method to the list view

        String[] list = library.listAllItems();
    int length = library.getItemsList().size();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        ObservableList<String> element = FXCollections.observableArrayList( list[i].toString());
        listView.setItems(element);
    }


    listView.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.SINGLE);

    btAdd = new Button("         Add");
    btCheckIn = new Button("     CheckIn ");
    btCheckOut = new Button("  CheckOut ");
    btDelete = new Button("      Delete ");

    FlowPane flowP = new FlowPane();

    listView.setPrefSize(400, 275);

    btAdd.setPrefSize(100, 25);
    btAdd.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_LEFT);
    btCheckIn.setPrefSize(100, 25);
    btCheckIn.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_LEFT);
    btCheckOut.setPrefSize(100, 25);
    btCheckOut.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_LEFT);
    btDelete.setPrefSize(100,25);
    btDelete.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_LEFT);

    flowP.getChildren().addAll(listView,btAdd,btCheckIn,btCheckOut,btDelete);

    Scene scene = new Scene (flowP,400,300);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Calculator");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
public static void main(String[] args)  {

    launch(args);
}
```

}

Code for Switch-Statement

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Code8 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MediaItem newItem = new MediaItem();
    Library library = new Library();
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int option = 0;
    while (option != 5)
    {
        option = library.displayMenu();

        switch(option)
        {
        case 1:
            System.out.print("What is the title? ");
            String newTitle = in.nextLine();
            newItem.setTitle(newTitle);

            System.out.println("What is the format? ");
            String newFormat = in.nextLine();
            newItem.setFormat(newFormat);

            library.addNewItem(newTitle, newFormat);
        break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("Which item (enter the title)? ");
            newTitle = in.nextLine();
            newItem.setTitle(newTitle);


            System.out.println("Who are you loaning it to? ");
            String name = in.nextLine();
            newItem.setLoanedTo(name);

            System.out.println("When did you loan it to them? ");
            String date = in.nextLine();

            library.markItemOnLoan(newTitle, name, date);


                break;
        case 3:
            String[] list = library.listAllItems();
            int length = library.getItemsList().size();
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                System.out.println(list[i].toString());
            }
            break;
        case 4:
            System.out.println("Which item (enter the title)? ");
            newTitle = in.nextLine();
            newItem.setTitle(newTitle);

            library.markItemReturned(newTitle);
            break;
        case 5:
            System.out.println("Goodbye");
            break;

        }// switch statement

    }//while statement
} //main method
```

}

Comment: Why are you mixing console input with GUIs?

Comment: i used console input to check if there are any neither errors nor exception. if all compiled, then I will use the handler and GUI. However, the point is that when I use GUIs String[] list = library.listAllItems(); this line return null.

Comment: I try to figure out what wrong. if I run it with console input, it compile, but using GUIs it throw NullPointerException